# What is "standard Kotlin package"?

Tags: list, kotlin

I am learning "Atomic Kotlin" course by Bryce Eckel and Svetlana Isakova. In topic **Lists** there is a phrase:

> `Lists` are part of the standard Kotlin package so they don’t require an `import`.

I've searched Internet but I cannot find the deterministic explanation of what is "standard Kotlin package".

`List` is declared in `kotlin.collections` that is in **Kotlin Standard Library** and for some reason I do not need to `import` it directly while `sin()` function is a part of `kotlin.math` that in turn also a part of **Kotlin Standard Library** BUT I have to `import kotlin.math` explicitly.

Can you help me to figure out where is the definition of "standard Kotlin package"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages that are imported by default are:

- kotlin.*
- kotlin.annotation.*
- kotlin.collections.*
- kotlin.comparisons.*
- kotlin.io.*
- kotlin.ranges.*
- kotlin.sequences.*
- kotlin.text.*

They are listed here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/packages.html#default-imports